# Avoid slow looping when plotting irregular raster plot using patches.Rectangle

Tags: python, performance, loops, matplotlib

I've written a code to make an irregular raster plot (i.e. one in which the size of the raster rectangles is variable).  Here is a minimum reproducible example below.

The problem is that looping over the blocks is very slow for my example (each plot has a lot of rectangles and there are a lot of plots to make).  I tried to convert the coordinates into a list of tuples, but that threw up an error.

Is it possible to get patches.Rectangle to return a list of patches, rather than one, so I can get rid of the loop over the patches and speed up the code?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colorbar as cbar

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1)

rng=6
plt.ylim(0,rng)
plt.xlim(0,rng)

N = 30
x = np.random.rand(N)*rng
y = np.random.rand(N)*rng
s = np.random.rand(N)
colors=np.random.rand(N)
normal = plt.Normalize(0,1) # my numbers from 0-1

cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
c=cmap(colors)

for i in range(N):
    val=0.5
    rect=patches.Rectangle((x[i],y[i]),s[i],s[i],
                            edgecolor='black',
                            linewidth = 1,
                            facecolor = c[i],
                            ) 
    ax.add_patch(rect)

cax, _ = cbar.make_axes(ax) 
cb2 = cbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cmap,norm=normal) 

plt.savefig("test.png")
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but maybe a [PolyCollection](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) might solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One sentence summary: Use a `PolyCollection`.

---

Using a collection to draw many shapes is sure more efficient than drawing individual rectangles. The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54463767/4124317) suggests to use a `PatchCollection`. Even more efficient is the use of a **`PolyCollection`**.

The reason is twofold:

1. In a PolyCollection you do not need to create each patch individually
2. It is sufficient to define exactly one shape, and only specify the sizes, colors and offsets.

I made some modifications to the code concerning the color definition (best let the collection do it for you) and the colorbar (use the collection, instead of an independen colorbar)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection, PolyCollection
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
```

PatchCollection:

```
def patchcoll(N, show=False):
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()

    rng=6
    plt.ylim(0,rng+1)
    plt.xlim(0,rng+1)

    x = np.random.rand(N)*rng
    y = np.random.rand(N)*rng
    s = np.random.rand(N)
    c = np.random.rand(N)
    norm = plt.Normalize(0,1) # my numbers from 0-1
    cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu_r

    pat = []

    for i in range(N):
        rect=patches.Rectangle((x[i],y[i]),s[i],s[i])
        pat.append(rect)

    col = PatchCollection(pat, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    col.set_array(c)
    col.set_edgecolor('k')
    col.set_linewidth(1.)
    ax.add_collection(col)


    fig.colorbar(col)
    if show:
        plt.show()
    else:
        fig.canvas.draw() 

    plt.close()
```

PolyCollection:

```
def polycoll(N, show=False):
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()

    rng=6
    plt.ylim(0,rng)
    plt.xlim(0,rng)

    x = np.random.rand(N)*rng
    y = np.random.rand(N)*rng
    s = np.random.rand(N)
    c = np.random.rand(N)
    norm = plt.Normalize(0,1) # my numbers from 0-1
    cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu_r

    offsets = np.c_[x,y]
    verts = list(zip([0,1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,1,0]))

    col = PolyCollection([verts], sizes=s, offsets=offsets, 
                         transOffset=mtrans.IdentityTransform(),
                         offset_position="data", cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

    col.set_array(c)
    col.set_edgecolor('k')
    col.set_linewidth(1.)
    ax.add_collection(col)

    fig.colorbar(col)

    if show:
        plt.show()
    else:
        fig.canvas.draw() 

    plt.close()
```

Single Rectangles:

```
def rectangles(N, show=False):
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()

    rng=6
    plt.ylim(0,rng)
    plt.xlim(0,rng)

    x = np.random.rand(N)*rng
    y = np.random.rand(N)*rng
    s = np.random.rand(N)
    c = np.random.rand(N)
    norm = plt.Normalize(0,1) # my numbers from 0-1

    cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu_r

    for i in range(N):
        rect=patches.Rectangle((x[i],y[i]),s[i],s[i], 
                               facecolor=cmap(norm(c[i])), edgecolor="k", linewidth=1)
        ax.add_patch(rect)


    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    sm.set_array([])
    fig.colorbar(sm)

    if show:
        plt.show()
    else:
        fig.canvas.draw() 

    plt.close()
```

Run all:

```
patchcoll(30, show=True)
polycoll(30,show=True)
rectangles(30,show=True)
```

#### Timing

For `N=1000` I get

```
%timeit(rectangles(1000))
757 ms ± 4.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit(patchcoll(1000))
184 ms ± 462 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit(polycoll(1000))
58.3 ms ± 146 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So in this case using a `PatchCollection` is a factor 3 more efficient than single rectangles, and using a `PolyCollection` is a factor 3 more efficient than a `PatchCollection`.

Overview of the time it takes to create a figure with `N` rectangles with the 3 different methods from above:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly how to time it, but it seems like that would be the perfect job for a [`PatchCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection). Does this speed up your graph at all?

**EDIT:** crude tests seem to show a gain of performance with `PatchCollection`, especially when N is large. I tested here with N=1000:

```
%timeit withCollection()
316 ms ± 5.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit withoutCollection()
772 ms ± 30.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colorbar as cbar
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

fig,ax=plt.subplots()

rng=6
plt.ylim(0,rng)
plt.xlim(0,rng)

N = 30
x = np.random.rand(N)*rng
y = np.random.rand(N)*rng
s = np.random.rand(N)
colors=np.random.rand(N)
normal = plt.Normalize(0,1) # my numbers from 0-1

cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
c=cmap(colors)
pat = []

for i in range(N):
    rect=patches.Rectangle((x[i],y[i]),s[i],s[i])
    pat.append(rect)

col = PatchCollection(pat)
col.set_facecolor(c)
col.set_edgecolor('k')
col.set_linewidth(1.)
ax.add_collection(col)


cax, _ = cbar.make_axes(ax) 
cb2 = cbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cmap,norm=normal)
```